# Which Java Collection would best back a Deck of Cards?

Tags: java, collections

I'm creating a `PlayingCardDeck` class in java, it's backed by a collection which holds my `PlayingCard` instances. My aim is make a literal simulation for different kinds of actual [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_techniques).

I've written a `compareTo` method that requires the contents of the deck (i.e. the contents of the collection) to be unique. I also need the collection to maintain insertion order for the purposes of simulating a shuffle

In essence I think it boils down to:

- Collection must exclude duplicates for `compareTo` function to work
- Must maintain insertion order so that shuffling the cards has an effect
- Being able to `pop` cards of the top atomically is a nice to have.

But I feel like I may have over complicated this, and that *I don't know which collection to use in which situation*.

Is there a natural fit for a collection that needs maintains insertion order and forbids duplicates? `ArraySet`?

Comment: How can something maintain insertion order **and** be sorted? Those two concepts are mutually exclusive. I'm not sure that your question is overly clear. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: How could the deck suddenly contain duplicate cards if it's you creating the cards to put in the deck?

Comment: Why would you want to "add hands to a map"?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Being sorted isn't the same as being sortable.

Comment: @BilltheLizard true, but any collection is _sortable_.

Comment: @BoristheSpider But not every collection maintains its insertion order.

Comment: @DaveNewton it shouldn't ever, but I have written the class so I could maybe take it out and use it elsewhere.

Comment: What if you're playing a two-deck game?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't like those games! I'm just simulating shuffles so right now I don't need to worry about it. After reading the answers though, I'll probably add a second parameter to my constructor so it reads `public PlayingCardDeck(int numberOfCards, boolean uniqueSetOfCards)` so I can change the behaviour.

Comment: I'd prefer factory methods, even if the underlying method is a constructor with a magic Boolean.

Comment: I think one important thing to point out is that `compareTo` **has no impact** on uniqueness in an ordinary set such as a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`; these use `equals` to define equality. `compareTo` only defines uniqueness in a `TreeSet`, which is an ordered collection.

Comment: @BoristheSpider At one point I was placing my Decks into a TreeMap which is why it is/was important.

Comment: @DaveNewton that'll be one more thing to learn :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `Set`; use whatever `Collection` is the easiest to code against - like a `List` (probably an `ArrayList`).

A `Set` would normally be used to ensure uniqueness when its elements are unknown (ie not generated by your code). You can ensure uniqueness through *logic* instead of the Collection type. But a Set is a poor fit when it comes to getting cards back out of it.

A `List` will let use use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to simplify shuffling your cards.

---

Not directly related to your question, but I would use enums for the `Suit` and `Rank` of your `Card` class. Using an enum will teach you the language and allow natural ordering of non-numeric face values (the picture cards) and a place to put custom ordering for the Ace (high/low) is required.

Create a `Hand` class that has a `List<Card>`, and a `Deck` class that has a `Card deal()` method. Something like that. Once you have all your classes and methods done, how to bring them all together should be obvious and easy.

Comment: Good advice as always @Bohemian. I'm still unsure where the OP's `Map` comes into it, so I'm not sure whether this fully answers the question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not actually sure what the question is to be honest. I'm going for broad advice for a broad question :/

Comment: I agree. I think the appeal of a set to OP is probably that it _enforces_ uniqueness, but that might not be a good thing in this context. If you add a duplicate to the set it will succeed, silently hiding an error in logic that will almost certainly be problematic (a card that shouldn't have existed in the first place just dissappeared into thin air).

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan that is a fantastic reason not to use a set....please see my reasoning in my edit as to why I way I wanted to - in short, it needs to be unique for my `compareTo` method to be correct.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm already using enums for the rank and suit, and (please see my recent edit) I won't be using `Collections.shuffle(List)`. But thanks for the 'hand'-y advice!

Comment: @Pureferret You can of course check the returned boolean after adding and throw an exception, but I think you'd be better off isolating code that adds or removes cards in small transactional methods, such as moveCard(List from, List To) and swapCards(List hand, int from, int to) that are easy to examine and test.

Answer (score 3):

I'd stick with an `ArrayList`.

- It will maintain insertion order (until you manipulate it).
- It's easily sorted.
- It's easily shuffled.

Also, there are many card games that allow multiple decks, so you might end up requiring duplicate cards.